# Evaluate product of normal CDF and PDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Is there anyway to evaluate $$\int_{C/B}^\infty \Phi(tA+ABx)\phi(x)dx?$$ 
>   $t,C\in\mathbb{R}$, $A>0$ and $B>0$.

I've tried differentiating under the integral but seems to get me nowhere. I differentiated w.r.t. $A$ and got a really complicated closed form solution. But to integrate that w.r.t to $A$ again seems even more hopeless...

Comment: $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denote the normal cdf/pdf, what is $f$? Assuming $A,B,t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: f is actually just the scaled reciprocal function. I've edited the problem to make it clearer. $t\in \mathbb{R}$ while $A>0$, $B>0$.